# Unable to access parent component value in child js controller lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to access parent component value in child component connectedcallback but showing as undefined..however, I am able to acess it in html but not in js.

Ex:

Child comp js:

```
@api res;    
connectedCallback()
        {
            getRecords()
            .then(data => {
                this.res = data;
                console.log('res'+JSON.stringify(this.res));
                console.log('data'+JSON.stringify(data));
                
            }).
            catch(error => {
                this.error = error;
                console.log('error'+JSON.stringify(error));
            })
        }
```

parent js:

```
@api orgdatafromp;
connectedcallback(){
console.log('orgdatafromp'+this.orgdatafromp);
}
```

orgdatafromp value is undefined.

what wrong i am doing here?

note :it bring the value in rendercallback

Comment: pass the data attribute in child component by calling a child component in Parent html . please share html code for better help

Answer (score 0):

Refer this it may be helpful:

https://salesforcediaries.com/2019/07/24/lwc-communication-part-1-passing-data-from-parent-to-child-component/

and if you want ot pass from connectedCallback then you should refer the same name and it should be used as attribute and pass the value to Child component. you can share html as well for better answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you call apex, it is called &asynchronously*. This means that the child connectedCallback happens *before* the Apex call completes. You can see the same problem if you write this:

```
@track res;
connectedCallback() {
    getRecords()
    .then(data => {
        this.res = data;
        console.log('res'+JSON.stringify(this.res));
        console.log('data'+JSON.stringify(data));
        
    }).
    catch(error => {
        this.error = error;
        console.log('error'+JSON.stringify(error));
    })
    console.log(this.res); // --> undefined
}
```

Note that `res` should **not** be marked as `@api`, because that means it is supposed to be read-only at the parent level.

Regardless, you can't access the data in the child on connectedCallback, as the Apex hasn't had a chance to run yet. Use a setter instead:

```
_orgdatafromp;
@api set orgdatafromp(value) {
  // Do something with the incoming value
}
get orgdatafromp(value) {
  return this._orgdatafromp;
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide an example who can we access get/set values between parent to child.

Comment: @Sravanthi The get/set methods are called when data moves between parent and child. The problem is that you need to wait until the Apex method returns a value.